# Firebase not listing the document values

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all the documents from a sub-collection in firebase firestore. This is my project structure

```
Users (Collection)
    |
    |
    Random User id (Document)
        |
        |
        Messages (Collection)
            |
            |
            Document 1
                Date: dateAdded
                String: message
                String: senderId
                String: recieverId
            |
            |
            Document 2
                Date: dateAdded
                String: message
                String: senderId
                String: recieverId
```

I try fetching these documents but they do not get listed in my app. This is what I tried so far.

```java
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(KeyUtils.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
    .document(new PreferenceManager(requireContext()).getString("uid"))
    .collection(KeyUtils.KEY_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
    .addSnapshotListener(((value, error) -> {
        for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges())
            if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED && (
                (documentChange.getDocument().getString("senderId").equals(new PreferenceManager(requireContext()).getString("uid")) &&
                documentChange.getDocument().getString("receiverId").equals(receiverId)) ||
                ((documentChange.getDocument().getString("senderId").equals(receiverId) && documentChange.getDocument().getString("receiverId").equals(new PreferenceManager(requireContext()).getString("uid"))))))
                messages.add(documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));

        messages.sort(Comparator.comparing(Message::getDateAdded));
        Collections.reverse(messages);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }));
```

These documents are listed in my android emulator. But not on my Samsung M30s android 11. My emulator is android 10.

#### Edit

This is the photo of my database:
[image]

Comment: `Thanks in advance ` you're always going to find someone removing this, there are even bots which would take this away, so you might as well just leave it out of your post to be honest :)

Comment: Sure. will not write next time onwards

Comment: it doesn't really make much of a difference, but it can be annoying to you if you keep getting notifications for changes to your posts, up to you really

Comment: If you're using hard-coded values, does it work?

Comment: Hope you are querying with same userID from your device and from emulator or userID you are querying is exists on database. @Sambhav.K

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say @JinalPatel. But according to what I understood, the user id is the random uuid generated while phone auth. And these documents do exist. Do you want me to add the pictures of the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo I will try that out and let you know

Comment: @Sambhav.K Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: @AlexMamo that does not work. It is not fetching the value still. And there is another issue now. The message is not being stored on the database but is visible on my sender mobile device. Reopening the app does not even show that message